# How to parse SQL syntax, tokenize SQL in Python

Tags: python, sql, tokenize

I need to parsing SQL syntax to get tables name in FROM and WHERE keyword if exists (root level, include sub query). For example:

```
Select * 
---
From a
Inner join b on a.c = b.c
---
Where a.o in (
  select o 
  from z
  where z.l in (
      select l 
      from a
  )
)

Output: From = [a,b], Where = [z,a]
```

I have to process all of type: select, insert, update, delete, select into, create

I have some idea such as:

- tokenlize sql statement
- find index of root FROM, root WHERE if exists (include subquery)
- split query to 2 part: from FROM to WHERE and from WHERE to end
- for each, find table name with regrex or some libraries

I try some libraries: sqlparse, sql_metadata, moz_sql_parser. But it is failed when query is complex. With sql_metadata, i will missing table name when comment -- exists, if remove comment with sqlparse, i will miss ')' somewhere... etc.

How to split part of FROM and part of WHERE
How to find table name in each

How to resolve it? Thank you

Comment: This blog should help you in a way, https://grisha.org/blog/2016/11/14/table-names-from-sql/

Answer (score 1):

Harvard's CS50 web [class](https://cs50.harvard.edu/web/2018/notes/3/) has the following code which I think helps you in it's last two lines.  Basically call upon the required result with result.field

```
  import os

  from sqlalchemy import create_engine
  from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

  engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")) # database engine object from SQLAlchemy that manages connections to the database
                                                    # DATABASE_URL is an environment variable that indicates where the database lives
  db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))    # create a 'scoped session' that ensures different users' interactions with the
                                                    # database are kept separate

  flights = db.execute("SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights").fetchall() # execute this SQL command and return all of the results
  
  for flight in flights
          print(f"{flight.origin} to {flight.destination}, {flight.duration} minutes.") # for every flight, print out the flight info
```